# $U$ linear and bounded, is an isomorphism $\iff$ $U$ is invertible and $U^{-1}=U^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

"Let $H$ and $G$ be Hilbert spaces and let $U:H \rightarrow G$ be a bounded operator.

Prove that $U$ is an isomorphism $\iff$ $U$ is invertible and $U^{-1}=U^*$."

I have denoted $U^*$ to be the adjoint of $U$ and an isomorphism is a linear surjection $A$ which fulfills $<Ah,Ag>=<h,g>$ for all $h,g \in H$

It is a theorem but my book left the proof as an exercise, it should be simple. Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$<Ux,Uy>=<U^*Ux,y>=<x,y>$. So, $U^*U=I$. Now, $U$ is also surjective, and so $U$ is invertible, and $U^{-1}=U^{*}$.

Conversely, let $U$ be invertible with $U^{-1}=U^*$. Then, $U$ is a surjection, and $<Ux,Uy>=<U^*Ux,y>=<Ix,y>=<x,y>$